# Make calculation on dataframe (divide each cell by last row in dataframe and calculate stuff)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a problem with making a calculation in my data frame. 
I have this equation:

> Q = (FL_18/Control(of the FL_18 column)) * (Control/Abs_18(of the Abs_18 column))

and that my data:

```
df <- structure(list(Layout = c("SM1_1", "SM1_2", "SM1_3", "SM1_4", 
"SM1_5", "Control"), Abs_18_mean = c(0.02753575, 0.04619625, 
0.04429875, 0.0485425, 0.033855, 0.062293375), FL_18_mean = c(2815.5, 
3330.25, 3375.375, 4458.5, 4905.5, 769.75)), .Names = c("Layout", 
"Abs_18_mean", "FL_18_mean"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to do it in dplyr, is it possible?

Comment: That data set reminds me of something

Comment: same problem, different day...

Comment: can you clarify this part of the equation ? (Control/Abs_18(of the Abs_18 column)

Comment: So in column Abs_18 last row - Control needs to be divided by rest of the columns. 

>  1 row: Control/SM1_1 
>  2 row:Control/SM1_2

Comment: Do you only have those 2 columns? (FL_18 and Abs_18)?

Comment: No I have 8 columns + Layout

Comment: How does the formula change? Because as is, you are doing FL18/cntl and cntl/Abs18 (i.e. different formula). So for your example you can do `l1 <- split(df[-1], df$Layout == 'Control'); mapply(function(x, y) (x[[1]]/y[[1]])*(y[[2]]/x[[2]]), l1[1], l1[2])` But I can't see a pattern to your formula in order to generalise it more

Comment: That basically works, do you think I can loop it each two columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Layout) %>% 
  mutate(Q=.$FL_18_mean[6]/FL_18_mean*Abs_18_mean/.$Abs_18_mean[6])
  # or a more general solution:
  # mutate(Q=.$FL_18_mean[.$Layout == "Control"]/FL_18_mean*Abs_18_mean/.$Abs_18_mean[.$Layout == "Control"])
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   Layout [6]
   Layout Abs_18_mean FL_18_mean          Q
    <chr>       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1   SM1_1  0.02753575   2815.500 0.12085071
2   SM1_2  0.04619625   3330.250 0.17141062
3   SM1_3  0.04429875   3375.375 0.16217252
4   SM1_4  0.04854250   4458.500 0.13453683
5   SM1_5  0.03385500   4905.500 0.08528004
6 Control  0.06229337    769.750 1.00000000
```

Comment: That looks good! but the problem is that i will have more columns, then I would have to specify them manually..

Comment: @magruc can't understand your problem.

Comment: So I have more columns with Abs and FL, not only two. Then the formula will be more complex

Comment: Sorry, but what is the problem then? If there are ten columns to be included, I see no issue to write the calculation once a time.

Comment: Yes, now it is 8 but it may be more in the future

Comment: You have to specify the columns either by `df[,1]/df[,2]` or by names as illustrated in the solution. So edit your question and inlcude a reproducible example showing your specific problem.  And please accept the answer if you are happy with it